# How to correctly pre-proccess data from dask dataframe to feed into ML model

Tags: python, dask

i'm working on a project with a very big dataset [NF-UQ-NIDS](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aryashah2k/nfuqnidsv2-network-intrusion-detection-dataset). I couldn't even fit in a pandas so I decided to use dask, but I'm having problems.

I might be doing something else wrong, but when I try to train_test_split X and y I can't do it without converting them to dask_array. The train_test_split results in the incorrect shape of y, which should be 7, since I use 7 classification labels, but it results in it being shape (x, 42), which is the same shape as X.

here is a reproducable sample, dataset is in the link above:

```
df = dd.read_hdf(root_folder+"hdf/"+hdf_name,hdf_name.split(".")[0])

def encode_numeric_zscore(df, name, mean=None, standard_deviation=None):
   if mean is None:
       mean = df[name].mean()

   if standard_deviation is None:
       standard_deviation = df[name].std()

   df[name] = (df[name] - mean) / standard_deviation

for column in df.columns:
if(column != 'attack_map'): encode_numeric_zscore(df,column) 

X_columns = df.columns.drop('attack_map')
X = df[X_columns].values
y = dd.get_dummies(df['attack_map'].to_frame().categorize()).values

print(type(X))
print(type(y))

X = df.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
y = df.to_dask_array(lengths=True)

print(type(X))
print(type(y))

X.compute()
y.compute()

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=2) 
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_val.shape, y_val.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem in train test split, then use the one from dask-ml while using a dask dataframe / series / array and not a sklearn train test split.
Link : https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.train_test_split.html